# How to use in FancyBox V4 the "afterShow" function or variable as it was possible in JQuery-FancyBox V3?

Tags: javascript, jquery, fancybox

We were using **the V3 version of Fancybox** with its `afterShow` function in which we included our `increaseImageClicks` and `increaseVideoClicks` function:

```
/* FANCYBOX OLD (https://web.archive.org/web/20210325170940/https://fancyapps.com/fancybox/3/docs/): */

    $("[data-fancybox]").fancybox({

        caption : function( instance, item ) {
            var caption = $(this).data('caption') || '';
            var siteUrl = $(this).data('siteurl') || '';


            if ( item.type === 'image' ) {
                caption = (caption.length ? caption + '<br />' : '')
                 + '<a href="' + item.src + '">View image</a><br>'
                 + '<a href="' + siteUrl + '">Visit page</a>';
            }
            else if ( item.type === 'video' ) {
                caption = (caption.length ? caption + '<br />' : '')
                 + '<a href="' + item.src + '">View Video</a><br>'
                 + '<a href="' + siteUrl + '">Visit page</a>';
            }
            
            return caption;
        },
        afterShow : function( instance, item ) {
            if (item.type === 'image') {
                increaseImageClicks(item.src);
            } else if(item.type === 'video') {
                increaseVideoClicks(item.src);
            } 
        }
    });
```

But, for some time, **we have decided to migrate to Version V4 of Fancybox by modifying our code like this:**

```
// FANCYBOX V4 (https://fancyapps.com/docs/ui/fancybox):
    Fancybox.bind("[data-fancybox='gallery']", {
        caption: function( instance, item ) {
            var caption = $(this).data('caption') || '';
            var siteUrl = $(this).data('siteurl') || '';


            if ( item.type === 'image' ) {
                caption = (caption.length ? caption + '<br />' : '')
                 + '<a href="' + item.src + '">View image</a><br>'
                 + '<a href="' + siteUrl + '">Visit page</a>';
            }
            else if ( item.type === 'video' ) {
                caption = (caption.length ? caption + '<br />' : '')
                 + '<a href="' + item.src + '">View Video</a><br>'
                 + '<a href="' + siteUrl + '">Visit page</a>';
            }
            
            return caption;
        },
    });
```

But there, despite much research, we don't see anywhere how to use the `afterShow` function in Version 4 of FancyBox.

**So how do I include my `increaseVideoClicks(item.src)` and `increaseImageClicks(item.src)` functions in FancyBox V4 ???**

Thank you please help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See docs here - https://fancyapps.com/docs/ui/fancybox/events - and use `done` event. Then the rest of the code would be basically the same.